# Moving google spreadsheet cursor to current date cell on open

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to move the view of my spreadsheet when it's opened to the current date.

It's a scheduling spreadsheet with a sheet for each month, with dates listed in the first column going down.

I've successfully got the sheet to change to the current month with the following code:

```
function gotoCurrentMonth() {
  var monthTabs = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

  var month = (new Date()).getMonth();  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(monthTabs[month]);
  sheet.activate();
}
```

This works with no problems when added to the onOpen function.

However the following code only works if it's triggered manually through the script editor, it doesn't seem to trigger when it's called after the gotoCurrentMonth function.

```
function gotoCurrentDay() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  //Get current day value from the MATCH spreadsheet function
  //Example of cell value: 73
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 2).getValue();

  //Go to bottom cell so that when it goes back up to current day, it's at the top of the screen
  sheet.setActiveCell(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1));
  Logger.log("Select Last Row: " + sheet.getLastRow());

  //Go back up to current day cell
  sheet.setActiveCell(sheet.getRange(range, 1));
  Logger.log("Select Current Day Row: " + range);
}
```

What happens is that the spreadsheet will switch to the March sheet when the spreadsheet opens, but the selected cell won't move. Sitting at the top of the March sheet.

If I then move my cursor back to January 1st (like it would normally when opened) and run the onOpen function manually after it's all loaded then it works fine and will select the current date properly.

My onOpen function:

```
function onOpen() {
  gotoCurrentMonth();
  gotoCurrentDay();
};
```

Any ideas as to why the onOpen function acts differently if it's activated manually or via the automated trigger?

Comment: I guess every sheet in your spreadsheet has cell 2,2 containing the match formula ? right ?

Comment: That's correct, however the Match formula will return #N/A on months that aren't the current month.

It's only on March that it currently has 73 in it.

Comment: maybe try to add a spreadsheetApp.flush() between the 2 calls to force the sheet to go to the right page before trying to get the value in cell 2,2

Comment: The flush didn't seem to help, I put it in the onOpen function between the gotoCurrentMonth and gotoCurrentDay.

It's worth noting that the gotoCurrentDay won't even move the active cell to the last cell, which doesn't rely on getting a value from a cell.

I move it to the last cell and back up, so that the current date will be at the top of the screen. But as I say, even that doesn't happen.

Comment: Ok, thanks for testing. I'll try to find and let you know later if I come up to something.

Comment: Did you try my code ? I set up an installable onOpen trigger calling the gotoCurrentMonthAndDay function and it works nicely. waiting for your feedback.

Comment: As per this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25724479/95750 you can now simply call activate() on the range and Sheets will scroll and select it. I tried it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to combine both functions in one... this code seems to be working as you expected :

```
function gotoCurrentMonthAndDay() {
  var monthTabs = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

  var month = (new Date()).getMonth();  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(monthTabs[month]);
  var row = sheet.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  sheet.setActiveCell(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1));//gets end of sheet
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();//update sheet
  Utilities.sleep(500);//pause 1/2 sec
  sheet.setActiveCell(sheet.getRange(row, 1));//activate on right date
}
```

As a bonus for anyone who would like to test, a small script to create the 12 sheets and delete them as well:

```
function createSheets(){
  var monthTabs = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
  for(var n in monthTabs){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(monthTabs[n]);
    Utilities.sleep(500);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().deleteSheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0])
} 

function deleteSheets(){
  var monthTabs = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November" ];
  for(var n in monthTabs){
    var del = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(monthTabs[n]);
    try{
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().deleteSheet(del);
    Utilities.sleep(500);
    }catch (err){Logger.log(err)};
  }
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].setName('Sheet1');
}
```

---

### EDIT :

Since it appears that your spreadsheet formula is causing some issues, here is a "pure JavaScript" approach to get the right day in the right sheet.
As they say in the tv serie "Fringe" these are 'parallel universes' or alternate reality... not always easy to go from spreadsheet to JavaScript and reverse ;)...

Anyway, a simple function that looks at every cell in col A and gets the day from the date and returns that value can be written as follows :

```
function getTodayRow(sheet){
  var colContent = sheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues();
  var today = new Date().getDate();
  var val=1;
  for(var n in colContent){
    if(new Date(colContent[n][0]).getDate() == today){val=Number(n)+1;break}
  }
  return val;// the +1 above is because arrays count from 0 and rows count from 1. (Number() is to avoid having 13+1=131 which is the default behavior unfortunately)
}
```

it takes the sheet object as argument and returns a number (returns 1 if no matching date was found so that in the worst case you go to the top of the sheet).

And your main function should be changed as well, it becomes :

```
function onOpen() { // I decided to call it simply onOpen to use the simple trigger that is sufficient in this case. Note that the user must have edit right for the script to run. 
  var monthTabs = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

  var month = (new Date()).getMonth();  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(monthTabs[month]);
  var row = getTodayRow(sheet);
  sheet.setActiveCell(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1));//gets end of sheet
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();//update sheet
  Utilities.sleep(500);//pause 1/2 sec, I saw your comment about timing... In my tests it works with 500 millisecs but adjust to your needs.
  sheet.setActiveCell(sheet.getRange(row, 1));//activate on right date
}
```

Comment: The sleep is the fix I was looking for, I didn't know you could put one in. It of course depends on the PC, but 500ms wasn't working reliably for me. Sometimes it'd work and sometimes not, upping it to like 2000ms seems to make it 100% reliable for me.

One thing though is that when running it still returns to row 73 from when I first posted the question (11th March). Even when the number at the top of the spreadsheet is showing 94... It's like it's not reading the updated value, I've set it to recalculate 'On change and every minute' in the spreadsheet settings; maybe it's related to that?

Comment: I've tried putting in a SpreadsheetApp.flush(); just before getting the Match value from the B2 cell and it still retrieves the wrong value. Possibly a bug with the actual Spreadsheet system?

Comment: You could easily get the current date with a simple javascript function and iterate in the right column until you find a match. Which column do you use for the dates ? are the dates "date only" ?, meaning hours minutes and seconds=0 ?

Comment: Dates are in the first column (A) and they are in the format "3/1/2014" in the cell/function value thing at the top. Although only the first date on each sheet is like that, the rest are like "=A2+1" if that makes any difference. Just want to say thanks for all the help so far Serge, you've been awesome! :D

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, I edited my answer with a version that doesn't make use of ss formulas... I don't like formulas !, one more reason not to like them ;)

Comment: Everything seems to be working perfectly now, thanks so much for your help Serge.

Even with this new search function the pause has to be pretty significant for it to work reliable for me. It's odd that it'll move down to the bottom of the spreadsheet fine but then not move back up.

Seems odd that it somehow buffers the first movement if it's made before the sheet loads but will then ignore any after that.

Either way it works fine, it's not like I'm going to be opening this thing enough to get bothered by the 2-second wait. :D