# When sheet is opened, would like to auto-jump to certain cell based on date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

UPDATE:  Based on earlier answers, I joined the chorus of people asking Google to re-enable the ability to do this, and they have apparently complied.

Now to figure out how to implement it since I know nothing about scripting in Google Sheets.

---

### ORIGINAL QUESTION BELOW

I have a spreadsheet with a number of different sheets that require daily entry of data. For example, there's a sheet called US-Sales, with a row for each day of the year. There are also several other identical sheets, like UK-Sales, US-Rentals, etc.

I would like focus to auto-jump to the proper row, based on the current date, whenever one of these sheets is opened.

Possible? If so, how?

Comment: answer updated with your specifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could normally be achieved by a simple script with an `onOpen()` function (that executes on spreadsheet opening) and activates the desired cell (or sheet)...

but, due to a change in the new version of spreadsheets (that you are most probably using) this is not possible anymore (for now), see [this issue (3928)](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3928) and feel free to star it so that hopefully Google team will change their mind and make it possible again ;-)

---

**edit** : this simple code works in [old version of spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dDBaU3doeGRmdFd1Mk12ak0yTDhTcmc&usp=sharing), it does not in new version.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0].getRange('B6').activate();// an arbitrary cell
  // not worth trying more complex cell selection (on date or anything else) while this is blocked by design .
}
```

Details on this change [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#april_2014) and below.
[image]

---

### EDIT 2 :

**On october 16 2014 this issue is now fixed and the code above works also in new version of spreadsheets.**  [details of issue here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3928)

to automatically activate the row corresponding to the day of the year you can use a code like below :

```
function onOpen() {
  var day = new Date().getDOY();// this uses a custom date method that returns the day of the year and is defined below
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0].getRange(day,1).activate();// in cloumn 1 for example. Add an offset if necessary (if headers...)

}

Date.prototype.getDOY = function() {
var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
return Math.ceil((this - onejan) / 86400000);
}
```