# Scroll all worksheets to last row on open

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I've built a spreadsheet that has 7 sheets, each of which is filled with many rows of data.  I got tired of manually scrolling down to the last row of each sheet, so I constructed a simple script function to programmatically find and go to a sheet's last row.  This function works, for the most part, when run manually.  However, when I tried to execute this function with a "From Spreadsheet, On Open" installed event trigger, it doesn't fire properly.

Here's the function:

```
function LastRowOnOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('302 Ashfrd'));
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

   lastRow = lastRow + 5;
   sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).activate();
   sheet.showSheet();

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('3220 Blmnt'));
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   lastRow = lastRow + 5;
   sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).activate();
   sheet.showSheet();

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('3302 Blmnt'));
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   lastRow = lastRow + 5;
   sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).activate();
   sheet.showSheet();

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('1035 Bnhm'));
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   lastRow = lastRow + 5;
   sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).activate();
   sheet.showSheet();

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Deer Park'));
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   lastRow = lastRow + 5;
   sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).activate();
   sheet.showSheet();

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('3000-102 Lrn'));
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   lastRow = lastRow + 5;
   sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).activate();
   sheet.showSheet();

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('2249 Wht'));
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
   lastRow = lastRow + 5;
   sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).activate();
   sheet.showSheet();
```

P.S.

I also tried using a for loop containing:

```
var sheet = SreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('2249 Wht'));
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
lastRow = lastRow + 5;
sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).activate();
sheet.showSheet();   `
```

varying the `sheet = getSheetByname` method to reduce lines of code, however all but the last iteration of the loop was ignored.

Comment: Write a macro that you bind to a keyboard shortcut, that selects the last row in the active sheet...

Comment: That's not a bad idea.  How does one "bind" a function to a keyboard shortcut?  ... I already have a script assigned to a drawing object (on each individual sheet) that moves to the last row of a sheet. What I want is to run the above script so that ALL sheets have been scrolled to the bottom when I open the spreadsheet.

Comment: Read the canonical documentation on the tag you chose? Google explains how to use the macro functionality.  As far as why your above code doesn't achieve your end goal of scrolling all sheets, there are other related questions that ask how to do this and should give you ideas on what to try.

Comment: Thanks @tehhowch ... I did as you suggested (bound the function to a keyboard shortcut (CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+ n) and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a good answer (that I could find) that addresses this topic in full:

The issue with your current script "ignoring" "all but the last iteration of the loop" stems from Google's own [internal optimizations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) of the Spreadsheet Service:

> Scripts commonly need to read in data from a spreadsheet, perform calculations, and then write out the results of the data to a spreadsheet. Google Apps Script already has some built-in optimization, such as using look-ahead caching to retrieve what a script is likely to get and write caching to save what is likely to be set.

In other words, your script is analyzed and effectively only the last `activate` call is determined to be needed. To counter this, we use [`SpreadsheetApp.flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) and [`Utilities.sleep`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds), as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22358918/9337071).

```
function onOpen(e) { // "Simple Trigger" from reserved function name.
  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#open
  scrollAll(e.source);
}
function scrollAll(wb) {
  (wb ? wb : SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).getSheets().forEach(
    function (sheet) {
      wb.setActiveSheet(sheet).setActiveSelection("A" + sheet.getLastRow());
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(1000); // may need to be adjusted
    });
}
function scrollActive() { // Macro target
  const s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  s.setActiveSelection("A" + s.getLastRow());
}
```

To have a keyboard shortcut to re-scroll the current sheet to the bottom, you would include the following in your project's [manifest file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros#manifest_structure_for_macros) to bind the `scrollActive` function as a macro with a keyboard shortcut:

```
"sheets": {
  "macros": [{
    "menuName": "Scroll To Last Row",
    "functionName": "scrollActive",
    "defaultShortcut": "Ctrl+Alt+Shift+N" // N= 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, or 0
  }]
}
```

Comment: This is great information.  I will definitely play with the flush and sleep methods.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you still need the answer or not since this thread was opened back in 2018 but I found the answer to your issue with "jumping to the last row" of an active spreadsheet [here](https://gist.github.com/primaryobjects/a9bf9ff1d2a7feb5ebd8888d67c0febb).

The script was written by Kory Becker (primaryobject) 6 months ago.

Comment: Of course with the caveat that the script will only execute for accounts with Editor permission.